# gdb - get variable name of register

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, cpu-registers

In GDB,  `info registers`    or   `info all-registers`  will show you all of the register symbol names and their values.

**Question:**

How do I get the *variable* name (i.e. from the source code) that is stored in that register?  (or a line number in source code, or anything)

For example:

```
int my_reg = /* something */;
float another_reg = /* something else */;
...
```

Then perhaps, `info all-registers`  will return:

```
R0             0x0      0
R1             0xfffbf0 16776176
R2             0x0      0
R3             0x0      0
R4             0x6      6
```

How do I determine which register (R0?  R2?  R4?) is "associated" with `my_reg`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the debug symbols (and understand how to read them - that is, you have some code that parses the debug symbols), it is possible to trace exactly which register corresponds to which register. However, this is quite possibly changing from one line to the next, as the compiler decides to move things around for one reason or another (e.g. some calculation starts with R1, and ends up with the result in R2, because that's better than trying to retain the value in R1 [or we need the original value in R1 too - think `array[x++]` - now we have the new value of `x`, hopefully in a register, and the value of the old `x` that we need to use for indexing, also needed to be in a register to add to the base-address of `array`.

Not all variables end up in registers (depending on processor, and "what registers are available").

The debugger *WILL* know where each variable is at any given time - but sometimes it can be a big confused, e.g:

```
int array[10000];
... 
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   array[i] = rand();
}
```

may translate to something like this during optimization:

```
int array[10000]; 
int *ptr = array;
int *ptr2 = &array[10000];
while(ptr < ptr2)
{
   *ptr++ = rand();
}
```

Now try printing `i`... ;)

Comment: So... how do I parse those debug symbols?  Is there some popular package for that?

Comment: With difficulty... Debug symbols are a complex description of what goes where during compilation. Different processor architectures (default to) different debug formats - what processor is this for?

Comment: The motivation is actually GPU's - I am trying to understand the register usage, because using too many registers-per-thread adversely affects GPU performance.  CUDA has wrapped GDB to create a "cuda-gdb".  It is the same as GDB plus a few features.  But this register naming problem is the same in both (gdb and cuda-gdb)

Comment: So, it probably is easier to look at the generated assembler output for functions, than it is to look at the debug format. But that's just a guess from my perspective.

Comment: But since I don't know what the debug format for CUDA-GDB is, I can't really say what "parser" you need for that. 

Note also that "register usage" isn't the same as "variables". Not all registers are variables, and not all variables are registers. If you do something like: x = r[i] + g[j] + b[k], the compiler use 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 registers to calculate that. And the code AROUND that calculation may of course already use some registers. It's a complex matter, and I think you see it as something relatively simple...

Answer (score 1):

There might be one register, multiple registers, or even no registers associated with any given C variable at any given point in time.  You'll have to inspect the disassembly to see what's going on.

Why not just `print my_reg` to see the value?

`l *$pc` will list the source code around the current instruction being executed.

Comment: Even if there are multiple registers associated with a variable, I still want to know when looking at the register.

Comment: I'm not sure that's an operation that makes sense.  Can't you just look at the disassembly and see?

Comment: I am actually coming from the other standpoint.  Given a list of registers, how do I map them onto variables?  This is the opposite of determining the value of a given variable.

Comment: But you can't - some registers may not be related to variables at all, some might be, and some might have once been, but are now just sitting unused.  Again, looking at the generated code is the only way to have that context.  Presumably that's what the debugger is doing.  Maybe there's a way for you to do the same?  Heck, even the debugger tends to do a bad job when trying to analyze this information for an optimized piece of code.

Comment: My register usage seems much higher than I expected, so I am trying to detangle all that, i.e. figure out why so many registers are being used, and what for

Comment: @MatthewParks: I don't mean to be difficult, but honestly - why do you care? The C optimiser is *meant* to find registers to use if it speeds up your code. Whatever it does could change with a new compiler release or a different compiler flag.  If you need to care about that kind of thing you should probably code in assembly.